# cpp array element repeat, but with different start

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a cpp array whose size is 5 including 3,4,2,5,1 as element.

I would like to make another array size 25, but element order like this:

3,4,2,5,1 / 4,2,5,1,3 / 2,5,1,3,4 / 5,1,3,4,2 / 1,3,4,2,5

If the array size is not big, then I can make the array manually.

But, if the array size is bigger, manual is not a good way.

So, I want to implement this array efficiently.

What is the best way to implement this array?

```
#include <iostream>

int array_a[5] = {3,4,2,5,1};
int array_b[25] = {};

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        array_b[i*5 + j] = array_a[(i + j) % 5];
    }
}
```

The modulus operator makes it cycle around to the beginning of `array_a`.